# Why does adding the integer 1 to another integer, then cast to a float give me .99?

Tags: floating-point, integer, processing, increment, rounding-error

I am in a visual programming class, trying to make a GUI in Processing that will eventually control an Arduino MeArm. I have a controlP5 element for each of the 4 servos, whose values are stored as int variables.

For example, my variable for the elbow would be:

```
eVal = (int)elbow.getValue();
```

I have some functions for storing a sequence to be played. When a step is run, it checks to see if the current value is equal to the value stored, and will add or subtract 1 til it gets there.

Here is a sample for the elbow:

```
if(eReset){
  if(eVal > currentStep[2])
    eVal --;
  else if(eVal < currentStep[2])
    eVal ++;
  else if(eVal == currentStep[2])
    eReset=false;

  println(eVal);
}
```

where currentStep is an array containing the values of each servo at a particular step. My problem is, that when I then set the servo value to the new value each frame,

```
elbow.setValue(eVal);
```

there are some numbers where it tries to add .99 instead of 1. One spot that I think of off the top of my head is going from 4 to 5, it gets stuck at 4.99 even though the print statement would show 5. This is at consistent intervals, as in this always happens going from 4 to 5 and a few other numbers. And I have absolutely no idea how to fix this because I'm only working with integers, so I'm not sure how a float snuck in there.

Edit:
This is in the setup() function-

```
int eVal = 0;

Slider elbow=cp5.addSlider("Elbow")
  .setRange(-100, 100)
  .setPosition(30, 330)
  .setSize(20, 240)
  .setValue(0);
```

Then in the draw() function-

```
eVal = (int)elbow.getValue();
//checks to see if the GUI needs to change eVal because of sequences
elbow.setValue(eVal);
```

The problem occurs when I try to increment or decrement eVal by 1 and then set the elbow value to it.

For example

```
//elbow.getValue() = 4.0
eVal = (int)elbow.getValue(); //eVal = 4;
eVal++; //eVal = 5
elbow.setValue(eVal); //elbow.getValue() should = 5
```

But for some reason, in that last line, the elbow value is set to 4.99, so when these calculations are run next frame, eVal is rounded back down to 4.

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Please post the setup code for the ControlP5 element, and the declarations of relevant variables like `eVal`.  Is `elbow` a ControlP5 element, and if so, what type? A slider, knob etc?  Note that `setValue()` for these elements does take a float as a parameter, not in integer, so there may be casting and rounding problems.  But the following is working as expected for me: `Slider mySlider; mySlider = cp5.addSlider("mySlider"); mySlider.setRange(0,10); mySlider.setValue(5);`

Comment: I just posted an edit here, which includes what I hope is a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. When I run just that new code in my edit, I still run into the problem. The problem isn't setting it to a hard value, it's when I increment my variable and then set it to that. Thank you for for taking time to look at my problem.